# Vanishing text into with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an Intro animation with some text for my personal website.
How can I add a text intro like this: https://codepen.io/nathanlong/pen/MyYqNd
over this css animation: https://codepen.io/gvrban/pen/rzNGpW

I've tried to copy/paste and merge the two pens but it doesn't work

I want the text to appear over the animation

Here is the code to the animation

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var texture_placeholder,
  isUserInteracting = false,
  onMouseDownMouseX = 0,
  onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
  lon = 90,
  onMouseDownLon = 0,
  lat = 0,
  onMouseDownLat = 0,
  phi = 0,
  theta = 0,
  target = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
animate();

function init() {

  var container, mesh;

  container = document.getElementById('container');

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  texture_placeholder = document.createElement('canvas');
  texture_placeholder.width = 128;
  texture_placeholder.height = 128;

  var context = texture_placeholder.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = 'rgb( 200, 200, 200 )';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, texture_placeholder.width, texture_placeholder.height);

  var materials = [

    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space4.jpg'), // right
    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space2.jpg'), // left
    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space1.jpg'), // top
    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space6.jpg'), // bottom
    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space3.jpg'), // back
    loadTexture('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/space5.jpg') // front

  ];

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 300, 300, 7, 7, 7), new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
  mesh.scale.x = -1;
  scene.add(mesh);

  for (var i = 0, l = mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {

    var vertex = mesh.geometry.vertices[i];

    vertex.normalize();
    vertex.multiplyScalar(550);

  }

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  //document.addEventListener( 'wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

  document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function loadTexture(path) {

  var texture = new THREE.Texture(texture_placeholder);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    overdraw: 0.5
  });

  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {

    texture.image = this;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

  };
  image.src = path;

  return material;

}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  isUserInteracting = true;

  onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
  onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

  onPointerDownLon = lon;
  onPointerDownLat = lat;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  if (isUserInteracting === true) {

    lon = (onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
    lat = (event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

  }
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

  isUserInteracting = false;

}

// function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

// camera.fov += event.deltaY * 0.05;
// camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

// }

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

  if (event.touches.length == 1) {

    event.preventDefault();

    onPointerDownPointerX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    onPointerDownPointerY = event.touches[0].pageY;

    onPointerDownLon = lon;
    onPointerDownLat = lat;

  }

}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

  if (event.touches.length == 1) {

    event.preventDefault();

    lon = (onPointerDownPointerX - event.touches[0].pageX) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
    lat = (event.touches[0].pageY - onPointerDownPointerY) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

  }

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  update();

}

function update() {

  if (isUserInteracting === false) {

    lon += 0.1;

  }

  lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat));
  phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
  theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon);

  target.x = 500 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
  target.y = 500 * Math.cos(phi);
  target.z = 500 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

  camera.position.copy(target).negate();
  camera.lookAt(target);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 8vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<img src="https://s3-us-west- 
        2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1037366/planet2.png">
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete.

Comment: see the codepen links i attached

Comment: @theenigma017 the code should be added to the question itself, not offsite links. You said you merged the code, edit the question to add that here. We're not going to visit two links and attempt to merge them for you.

Comment: Oh, I was going to do that but the site alert said i need to include code from the codepen links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged both the codepens into one.

I've simply changed the class

```
.intro {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}
```

to

```
.intro {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      z-index: 2;
     }
```

When using position absolute, `z-index` is used to bring the object/element on top of each other (imagine a layered structure). Element with highest `z-index` will appear on the top of all elements with position set to absolute.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) is more info on z-index.

Have look at [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BejmmP). Hope this is the desired output.